# HTML and JQuery in Webstorm IDE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very basic problem. I have a webstorm project with an HTML file, CSS file, and JS file.

I created a circle with "div" and tried to make it fade after clicking in the JS. It's not working.

One thing to add, I have sourced the Jquery API from google APIs, but also downloaded a different one into the global libraries on the webstorm IDE. I don't know if that causes any problems

HTML, CSS, JS follow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='bounce.js'></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ball" id="mb" ></div>
</body>
</html>

.ball {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:blue;
    border:2px solid;
    border-radius:100%;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
        $('div').fadeOut('slow')
    });
});
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Put the `jQuery` script before `bounce.js`

Comment: and time to go to the basics. readout the docs...;) http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: thanks guys.. there is literally another thread out there where some "pro" specificaly said put your script tag to the js script BEFORE the  one to jquery. that's why I had it backwards. thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

.. add the style and script tags ... works a treat ... EJK

```
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='bounce.js'></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ball" id="mb" ></div>
    </body>
</html>

<style>
.ball {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color:blue;
border:2px solid;
border-radius:100%;
}
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
    $('div').fadeOut('slow')
    });
    });
</script>
```

.. hope this helps .. EJK

Comment: EJK,Sorry, I should have been more clear. The HTML, CSS, and Javascript are in separate files. It's not all done in the HTML file. So I think the bracket separators won't make a difference.. any other ideas?

Comment: No probs ... whats the bounce.js do (other than making something bounce) ... presume this bounces the ball?

Comment: A_nobody, bounce.js is the javascript block at the bottom. 3 blocks, HTML, CSS and Javascript.  The javascript literally is just fading out the div when it's clicked...

Comment: Hi again ... okay so bounce.js is your script ... cool ... is it working now as Anton's suggestion is valid ... you must have loaded the JQuery library in the header before the JQuery script runs or else JavaScript won't know what to do with it ... your code is fine ... as I said works a treat ... here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eamonnkillian/EQN38/ ...